# Vector Spaces and Polynomial Rings

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

در تعریف فضای برداری در ویژگی آخر داریم به ازای هر ایکس متعلق به فضای برداری و1 متعلق به میدان  داریم یک متعلق به میدان ضرب در ایکس متعلق به فضای برداری برابر باایکس دنبال ی مثال از ش می گردم تو تابع ها و ماتریس ها که یک میدان ضرب در عضو متعلق به فضای برداری برابر با عضو متعلق به فضای برداری نشود برام ی مثال بزنید.

سوال دوم در جبر 1 می دونیم که گروه ای سه یکریخت با گروه زد سه است می خوام بدونم میشود حلقه چند جمله ای ها رو روی ای سه در نظر گرفت  یا نه و اگه جواب مثبت باشه ضرایب در حلقه چند جمله ای به چه صورتی در میان.

---

### translations:

**Translation of the first question**:

Let $V _F$ be a vector space on $F$ ($F$ is a field).

In definition of vector space the last feature said:

$$\forall x\in V ,1\in F\quad x\cdot1=x.$$
Please give an example such that multiplication of   function and matrix In member of vector space doesn’t belong to vector space (i mean  if $a\in{V_F}$ then is there $x\in{\text{ function and matrix }}$: $ax\notin V_F$  ?)

**Translation of the second question** (Please correct if needed)

We already know from Algebra I that the group $\mathbb{E}_3$ is isomorphic to group $\mathbb{Z}_3$. I want to know whether it is possible to consider polynomial ring on $\mathbb{E}_3$  ? If so what are the coefficients of polynomial ring?

---

**Rough translation**, courtesy of [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/)

> Define the vector space of the last feature we have for every x belonging to the vector space and one belonging to the field have a reserved field multiplication in X belongs to the space taken up Baayks for example, the S'm your function and matrix, a square multiply the member belongs to a member belonging to the same vector space vector space example does not check for me.
>    
>  
>   The second question in algebra 1 know that the group of three uniformity with his three'm wondering if the ring polynomials on three consider whether, and if so, if the coefficients in the ring of polynomials in what form the .

Comment: @DannyCheuk That seems a little insensitive.

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/what-is-the-site-etiquette-about-i-asking-and-ii-answering-questions-in-a-la

Comment: It looks as if human translators can feel secure for a while.

Comment: For clarification: It is [okay to post non-English questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617/what-is-the-site-etiquette-about-i-asking-and-ii-answering-questions-in-a-la). We would be greatly obliged if someone capable of translating the question would do so. This is not sufficient reason in my book to downvote a question. On the other hand, as this question currently stands, it is not answerable, so I won't reopen it. If this question gets translated, ping me and I will reopen.

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo, it is nice that you are trying to help, but there is no way to put the words function and matrix together and get sense out of it. Perhaps if you learned the exact book this person is reading, and the pages?

Comment: @ Will Jagy:this question is unclear for me too i want ask her to modify it  but i think she abandon here

Comment: @MaisamHedyelloo, that happens quite a bit, some people post questions and then walk away or go to sleep. And it is usually the least experienced people who are likely to post a poor question but also disappear. So, you have tried to help; forget about this for, say, 24 hours.

Comment: @Will Jagy: yeah i agree with u .thanks

Comment: @Ensieh Please first translate it to English then __leave a comment__ for moderators to reopen it.

Comment: @Mahdi Khosravi:hi dear mahdi please translate second question .i do first part of it .

Comment: As it currently stands, the question is rather hard to understand (I can certainly not make any sense of it). Please, if you use an automated translator, at least read through the translation and see if it seems to make sense before editing it in.

Comment: If this is what the question looks like after 14 revisions, I think it's time to give up on it. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb{Z}_3$ as a group is not suitable for a vector space, because vector spaces are considered over fields, not groups. However, if you think of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ as a field, then yes, it's possible to do so, and if something is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$ as a field, then yes, you can simply replace $\mathbb{Z}_3$ by that and nothing would change.

I don't know what you mean by $\mathbb{E}_3$ though. You can consider the polynomial ring over any arbitrary commutative ring. I mean you can even consider the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. As you know $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, because, for instance, 2 does not have a multiplicative inverse but still it's possible to study the ring of polynomials over integers. We even have a good understanding of the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. It's also possible to study polynomial rings in non-commutative algebra but the generalization isn't completely straightforward.